# How to Display Table data horintally in visualforce Page?

Tags: salesforce, visualforce, salesforce-lightning

I was not able to display records in horizontally.
In a table am retrieving Name,Roll_Number,School_Name,Grade,School_Phone and Date_of_Birth  from custom_object__c. Now i want to show these item horizontally in Visualforce pages.
below are image attached as i required. please help

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to craft it bit more manual, don't think `<apex:datatable>` and `<apex:pageBlockTable>` can create something like this, at least not without some CSS tricks.

See if this gets you somewhere:

```xml
<apex:pageBlock>
    <apex:pageBlockSection columns="2">
        <apex:repeat value="{!contacts}" var="c">
            <apex:outputField value="{!c.Name}" />
            <apex:outputField value="{!c.Roll_Number__c}" />
            <apex:outputField value="{!c.School_Name__c}" />
            <apex:outputField value="{!c.Grade__c}" />
            <apex:outputField value="{!c.School_Phone__c}" />
            <apex:outputField value="{!c.Date_of_Birth__c}" />
            <!-- 
                if you want visual gaps - you could put pageBlockSections in the loop!
                or add some blank elements
            -->
            <apex:pageBlockSectionItem />
            <apex:pageBlockSectionItem />
            <apex:pageBlockSectionItem />
            <apex:pageBlockSectionItem />
        </apex:repeat>
    </apex:pageBlockSection>
</apex:pageBlock>
```

If you need it without Salesforce styling (but can't simply `<apex:page standardStylesheets="false"`) - you can still use this structure to output raw html `<table>, <tr>, <th>, <td>` etc. There are lots of samples how to do raw html output, especially for pdf. Shameless plug: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/194196/799